# Creating a web server in iOS application only for one page

Tags: html, ios, swift, sockets, webserver

I have to create a simple web server in Swift or Obj-C for an iOS application.

In fact it has to be the simplest web server ever because it just has to create a socket or whatever to listen to a web page request.

Then it has to provide the HTML string when the request comes.

That's all, no other feature from a real web server needed.

It has to respond only to a single type of requests

```
localhost:port/page_number.html
```

or with different alias, like

```
alias/page_number.html
```

Is it possible?

I read an example for Mac OS, with very short source code, but I also found examples for iOS that have many source code files and they are not simple at all.

The Mac OS example leverages Darwin library. Maybe it is so powerful that a simple web server is possible with a few instructions.

It is from [Tiny http server engine written in Swift programming language](https://iosexample.com/tiny-http-server-engine-written-in-swift-programming-language/)

Here is the code:

```
import Darwin.C
let zero = Int8(0)
let transportLayerType = SOCK_STREAM // TCP
let internetLayerProtocol = AF_INET // IPv4
let sock = socket(internetLayerProtocol, Int32(transportLayerType), 0)
let portNumber = UInt16(4000)
let socklen = UInt8(socklen_t(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.size))
var serveraddr = sockaddr_in()
serveraddr.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
serveraddr.sin_port = in_port_t((portNumber << 8) + (portNumber >> 8))
serveraddr.sin_addr = in_addr(s_addr: in_addr_t(0))
serveraddr.sin_zero = (zero, zero, zero, zero, zero, zero, zero, zero)
withUnsafePointer(to: &serveraddr) { sockaddrInPtr in
  let sockaddrPtr = UnsafeRawPointer(sockaddrInPtr).assumingMemoryBound(to: sockaddr.self)
  bind(sock, sockaddrPtr, socklen_t(socklen))
}
listen(sock, 5)
print("Server listening on port \(portNumber)")
repeat {
  let client = accept(sock, nil, nil)
  let html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body style='text-align:center;'><h1>Hello from <a href='https://swift.org'>Swift</a> Web Server.</h1></body></html>"
  let httpResponse: String = """
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    server: simple-swift-server
    content-length: \(html.count)

    \(html)
    """
  httpResponse.withCString { bytes in
    send(client, bytes, Int(strlen(bytes)), 0)
    close(client)
  }
} while sock > -1
```

But I know that iOS is advanced too, so maybe there is a very compact code to create that web server minimal capability on iOS.

Comment: what's the scope of this question (iOS app you plan to submit to the store, or enterprise one, or testing, or some inter-app communication)? And what's the end goal of this "serving a single page" server? For example if you just want to display a page, you could simply use WKWebView or Safari.

Comment: @thiscommunityistoxic the purpose is opening that page in Safari, not the WKWebView. I know it is strange. I will ask in the Apple developer forum if it is allowed, but first I want to know if it is technically feasible. WKWebView has differences, and a complex handling of certain aspects would be necessary.

Comment: in that case maybe just import GCDWebServer (https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer), or use it as a prototype, at least it's written for iOS, not Mac

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very basic and simplified http server implementation in Swift that might be enough for your case if you do not want to use external libraries:

```
class PicoHttpServer {
    private static var serverSocket: Int32?
    private static let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.pico.http.server.queue")
    private static let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)
    static func httpOkResponse(html: String) -> String {
        return "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nServer: PicoHttpServer\r\nContent-Length: \(html.count)\r\n\r\n\(html)"
    }
    static func start(port: UInt16 = 7000, address: UInt32 = INADDR_LOOPBACK, requestHandler: @escaping ((String) -> String)) {
        semaphore.wait()
        let started = serverSocket != nil
        semaphore.signal()
        if started {
            return
        }
        queue.async {
            realStart(port: port, address: address, requestHandler: requestHandler)
        }
    }
    static func stop() {
        semaphore.wait()
        if let serverSocker = serverSocket {
            close(serverSocker)
        }
        serverSocket = nil
        semaphore.signal()
    }
    private static func realStart(port: UInt16, address: UInt32, requestHandler: ((String) -> String)) {
        let tcpSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)
        if tcpSocket == -1 {
            return
        }
        serverSocket = tcpSocket
        var reuseOn = Int32(1)
        setsockopt(tcpSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuseOn, socklen_t(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: reuseOn)))
        var socketAddress = sockaddr_in()
        socketAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
        socketAddress.sin_port = port.bigEndian
        socketAddress.sin_addr = in_addr(s_addr: address.bigEndian)
        socketAddress.sin_zero = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        let socklen = UInt8(socklen_t(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.size))
        let bindResult = withUnsafePointer(to: &socketAddress) { sockaddrInPtr -> Int32 in
            let sockaddrPtr = UnsafeRawPointer(sockaddrInPtr).assumingMemoryBound(to: sockaddr.self)
            return bind(tcpSocket, sockaddrPtr, socklen_t(socklen))
        }
        if bindResult == -1 {
            return
        }
        let listenResult = listen(tcpSocket, 5)
        if listenResult == -1 {
            return
        }
        print("Server started")
        while(true) {
            semaphore.wait()
            let stopped = serverSocket == nil
            semaphore.signal()
            if stopped {
                break
            }
            let mtu = 65536
            let client = accept(tcpSocket, nil, nil)
            if client == -1 {
                continue
            }
            var buffer = Data(repeating: 0, count: mtu)
            let readResult = buffer.withUnsafeMutableBytes { pointer in
                return read(client, pointer.baseAddress, mtu)
            }
            if readResult == -1 {
                continue
            }
            let clientData = buffer.subdata(in: 0..<readResult)
            let clientRequest = String(data: clientData, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
            let response = requestHandler(clientRequest)
            response.withCString { bytes in
              write(client, bytes, Int(strlen(bytes)))
              close(client)
            }
        }
        print("Server stopped")
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as below to response with different html for each page number:

```
PicoHttpServer.start { request in
    if request.hasPrefix("GET /1.html") {
        return PicoHttpServer.httpOkResponse(html: "<html><body>Page 1</body></html>")
    } else if request.hasPrefix("GET /2.html") {
        return PicoHttpServer.httpOkResponse(html: "<html><body>Page 2</body></html>")
    } else {
        return PicoHttpServer.httpOkResponse(html: "<html><body>Other page</body></html>")
    }
}
```

Note that if you want to open this from your app in Safari as you wrote in the comment to the question then you will probably also need to create a background task with UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask so that your app can run this server at least for a moment when your iPhone app goes to background.